# Color code font to 1) function arguments and 2) iterators in loops

Tags: r, rstudio, code-formatting

I would like function arguments and iterators in loops to have a different color than the rest of the code. I am currently using the 'Merbivore Soft' theme, and in the code below...

```
fn <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

a <- c("Hello", "Gutentag", "Bonjour")

for (g in a) {
  fn(g)
}
```

...'function', 'for', and 'in' are orange, '"Hello"' and other greetings are green, while the rest of the text is white. I would like 'x' and 'g' to have a different color than white.

Setup details:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
RStudio/2023.03.1+446
Windows 11.
```

Comment: I think the way to accomplish this is to change the RStudio theme. Search the internet for themes like https://github.com/jnolis/synthwave85 This is also interesting: https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/ui/appearance.html Fyi, Germans write "Guten Tag". ;)

Comment: @Friede in the https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/ui/appearance.html, from the differents "scopes" in tmTheme and "selectors" in rstheme, it does not seem there is any way to apply colors specifically to functions arguments and iterators :( and pardon my German!